# How to toggle Dropdown by scrolling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have designed a page with Bootstrap 4 Beta. I have a navbar (fixed-top), which contains a dropdown menu. I want to toggle this menu, when the page is scrolled, so it would have the following behavior:

- If scrolled to the top of the page, open Dropdown menu
- Else close it
- This effect should only occur, when the navbar is not collapsed (caused by responsive breakpoint)
- The menu should remain toggleable by a user

```js
// Closing or opening Dropdown, when window is scrolled
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($("#mobile-only").is(':hidden')) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
      $("#example-dropdown").dropdown('toggle');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <!--...-->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div id="example-dropdown" class="dropdown">
        <a id="example-dropdown-link" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="example-dropdown-link">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="mobile-only" class="row d-sm-none">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div style="height:1000px;">
  <p>Dummy Container to generate scrollbar</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I have added my approach. It's runnable.

- The event only triggers, when a mobile only div is not visible. Check!
- The Dropdown opens, when I scroll to the top of the page. Check!
- How do I close it? Bootstrap does not seem to ship a function for that.
- Also once triggered, the Dropdown is not manually toggleable any more

Comment: What have you tried so far, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service?

Comment: I don't have much jQuery knowledge, so I thought a more common question would be appropriate. But ok, I will edit my Post.